# SwiftUI: NavigationLink to DetailView within TabView Crashes

Tags: swift, swiftui

Currently, if I try to type in a `TextField` nested twice within a `List` then `Detail View`, my app crashes with the error: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` and in the debugger (abbreviated):

```
CoreSimulator --- Device: iPhone 8 (---) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (----) - DeviceType: iPhone 8
AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid size for indirect attribute: 73 vs 1.
```

Here's the code that leads to this error.

```
struct RootView {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ListView()
                .tag(0)
        }
    }
}
struct ListView {
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $isActive)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Keyboard appears and the app crashes.", text: $text)
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this? If I remove the TabView then it works just fine. I need the TabView though, so is there a way I can pop out of the TabView then render a Detail View outside of TabView?

**EDIT:** Using `UITabViewController` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable` resolved the issue. Seems the issue is with `TabView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code with some adjustments, seems to work fine with me what version of ios/xcode do you use?

```
import SwiftUI
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                ListView().tabItem {
                    Text("test")
                }
                ListView2().tabItem {
                    Text("test2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            NavigationLink("test", destination: DetailView(), isActive: $isActive)
        }
    }
}

struct ListView2: View {
    @State var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            NavigationLink("test2", destination: DetailView(), isActive: $isActive)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Keyboard appears and the app crashes.", text: $text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a scrollview a layer above the NavigationView? I had forgotten to add that to the sample. My app crashes when I use that structure.

Comment: Put your navigation view in the rootview, it should only be declared once. I've updated my code.